# is it possible to skin the application based on the target mobile device using phonegap?

Tags: cordova

We are planning to use phonegap for our application development and doing POC. I want to know whether it is possible to skin the application based on the target mobile device using phonegap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still very much new to PhoneGap, but I believe this is possible. PhoneGap has a [Device Object](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_device_device.md.html), which gives some nice insight into the target device. Through a combination of the [Device Platform](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.platform) and [Device Version](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.version) properties, you should be able to gather what you need.

Keep in mind though that with PhoneGap, you're not creating one app that will then magically work on all devices. You'll still be using Xcode to create an iPhone version, Eclipse to create an Android version, etc. So it may or may not be easier to manually swap out files based on platform, as opposed to doing so programmatically.

Comment: Got it. Can supply different css based on the requested device platform. Thx.